# Creating installer for CLI tool made with Rust

Tags: rust, installation, deployment, environment-variables, rust-cargo

I've made a simple CLI tool which contains a few minigames. It's written in entirely in Rust [(See the repo here if you're curious)](https://github.com/mmmmminty/terminal_mints). I have been using the Cargo command `cargo install --path .` to be able to use it from any terminal on my system (using MacOS). I want to be able to release a version on my Github for others to run the binary from their terminals as well.

I've never released any of my projects before, and am quite unfamiliar with how releases work, or how to create an installer for my binary. From my understanding, it should be possible to install my app binary and the relevant environment variable(?) without the user needing to install Cargo. I do recall having to manually fiddle with my env-variables to get it working.

The important distinction is that the tool is run within the terminal, not through opening the executable (by simply typing `mints <game> <args>`). Could someone provide guidance on how I can build an installer that sets it up correctly/anything I should know about creating releases for CLI's like this? Thank you!

Comment: Why not just pick some supported targets and offer pre-compiled binaries? Cross compilation is easy in rust. Alternatively, does github offer CI/CD for rust?

Comment: @MeetTitan I should have clarified, that's what I'd like to do. I understand how to create the pre-compiled binaries, but I don't understand how to offer it so that all they need to do is launch the installer for their platform, then simply type `mints <game> <args>` into the terminal. I want to make installation as simple as possible, without requiring installing the rust toolchain, or fiddling with env-variables.

Comment: You might want to look at [cargo-dist](https://github.com/axodotdev/cargo-dist), which was created for distributing binaries like this.

Comment: You don't technically have to install a statically linked binary. You could add a note about moving the binary to/setting different dirs for the users `$PATH` variable (your users will be cli users, they should be comfortable doing `mv mybin ~/bin` and making sure it's in path), or write a wrapper (could be in rust if you caught the bug) that does that, but that's overkill for a cli app in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, it sounds like what you want is to build for multiple targets and commit those builds into a repo that others can clone and just run?

That can be accomplished with the `cargo build` command and passing different values to --target, such as:

`cargo build --target x86_64-apple-darwin` // to build for 64 bit macOS

`cargo build --release --target x86_64-apple-darwin` // <- or this

> add the flag --release to put the output binary into `./target/releases/` instead of `./target/debug/`

So you'll need to build a binary for each individual target platform you want to support, and then you'd think you can just make sure the files have the correct permissions: (`chmod 755 ./target/releases/yourbinarysname`) **BUT** this is where it gets a bit tricky, because `git` isn't going to preserve whatever file permissions you set on *your system* and copy that to *someone else's* system.

So instead, you could make a simple bash script that sets the permissions of the executable and moves the file into the user's PATH (by copying it into one of the bin directories available on their PATH environment variable.) and then finally, after copying the binary to an appropriate bin location, you could have the bash script open your program for them.

This would avoid the need for them to install cargo, but would require a bit of extra work on your part to detect which platform they're on and figure out which target build to move into which location for them.

##### side notes:

1. Pertaining to: "The important distinction is that the tool is run within the terminal, not through opening the executable (by simply typing mints  )."

> It's important to note that a user opening a program via the terminal ***is*** the same thing as running the executable (binary/the final output of your rust build or rust install). The cargo build or cargo install step produces an executable and in the case of install, it moves that executable file into the .cargo/bin directory for you, so the custom bash script I'm suggesting you make would be replacing the functionality of cargo install without them needing to install anything so long as they're already running bash locally.

2. You can also include the following lines in your `Cargo.toml` to control the file name that gets output from a `cargo build`:

```ini
[[bin]]
name = "yourcustombinaryname"
path = "src/main.rs"
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand how to build pre-compiled binaries for different targets, but like I mentioned in a comment above, I'm confused on how to make installation as simple as possible for users. Ideally, you download the correct release for your system, then all you have to do is launch the installer, then once it's complete, you can just type `mints <game> <args>` in any terminal and it works. I will give the bash script ago though, appreciate the response :)

Comment: if you wanted you could make one bash script for each specific OS/build target and then people can run the installer for their specific environment. that would actually probably be simpler than trying to handle every possible case in one bash script haha, but yeah you just set the file permissions so it's executable by the user, then move the binary into ~/.bin or whichever bin you need for the given build target and they should then be able to invoke the program by typing the name of the binary file in any terminal where said bin is in their PATH, and optionally adding any args ^.^